# perl matching optional regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm struggling to come up w/ a regex in Perl to match a string with optional prefixes and suffixes.

Here is my expression so far:

```
my $string = "prefix1_foo_suffix2";
if ($string =~ m/^(prefix1_|prefix2_)?(prefix3_|prefix4_)?foo|bar(_suffix1|_suffix2)?$/) {
  print "match"
};
```

So this should match strings like

```
prefix1_foo_suffix2
prefix1_prefix4_bar
bar_suffix2
```

but not

```
prefix1_baz_suffix2
bar_suffix42
```

As far as I can tell, though, this is matching any suffix (ie: anything after "foo" or "bar").  Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Comment: That'll be because it's optional, in other words: all that needs to match is **foo|bar**, and *bar_suffix42* qualifies.  I'd be surprised if prefix1_baz_suffix2 did, though, as baz isn't part of your required match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex has issues with precedence. Also, for non-capturing groups you should use `(?:group)`.

Here is what you wrote:

```
m/  (?: ^ (?: prefix1_ | prefix2_ )? (?: prefix3_ | prefix4_ )? foo )
  | (?: bar (?: _suffix1 | _suffix2 )? $ )
/x
```

But you meant something like:

```
m/  \A
    (?: prefix1_ | prefix2_ )?
    (?: prefix3_ | prefix4_ )?
    (?: foo      | bar      )
    (?: _suffix1 | _suffix2 )?
    \z
/x
```

Quick test:

```
my $regex = qr/
    \A
    (?: prefix1_ | prefix2_ )?
    (?: prefix3_ | prefix4_ )?
    (?: foo      | bar      )
    (?: _suffix1 | _suffix2 )?
    \z
/x;
say "$_:\t", ($_ =~ $regex ? "passes" : "doesn't match") for
  qw/prefix1_foo_suffix2
     prefix1_prefix4_bar
     bar_suffix2
     prefix1_baz_suffix2
     bar_suffix42
  /;
```

Output:

```
prefix1_foo_suffix2:    passes
prefix1_prefix4_bar:    passes
bar_suffix2:            passes
prefix1_baz_suffix2:    doesn't match
bar_suffix42:           doesn't match
```